# Windows gadget - rounded corners

Tags: javascript, css, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

Is there any way how to create border-radius for an element in windows gadget? I tried to use ie-css3.htc but doesn't work. Any ideas ?

//edit: I'd like to reconstruct my question. I am looking for solution which wouldn't need to use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the gadget itself, try creating a top portion, a repeating middle, and a bottom portion.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not sure what you mean. Please, could you explain ?

Comment: Have three elements, a top part (with rounded corners), a middle part (as repeating background), and bottom part (with rounded corners). Have the top, middle, and bottom elements, be images with the rounded corners, hence the transparency.

Comment: I edited my question sorry, I don't want to use images, just something that rounds <div> corners.

Comment: @adman: You may always use CSS3 - Border Radius. This will allow you to define top, bottom, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right borders and how rounded they are. Follow the link below:
http://border-radius.com/